# How to Troubleshoot High Voltage Short/Ground (Furnace Sparking)

Tags: ground, troubleshooting, spark

**11/17 results:** Manually turned on heat on the thermostat (you will know what I mean) - lit right up.

Thank you all yet again. I have heat...which I will be turning off at night and keeping a fire detector for safety reasons until I figure out the short fully, but nonetheless.

[image]

[image]

---

**Background:**

1. Turned on furnace from the 60s or 70s (guess, don't have model).
2. Realized it's not heating.
3. Went to panel. Every 5 seconds there was a spark on what I presume to be a gas venting pipe (yes, I realize the danger). The pipe was very hot, but did not shock me. The spark gap was bad enough to essentially cut into the pipe - there are metal shavings under it.
4. I inserted a toothpick between the pipe and the metal bracket (attached to furnace body) holding it to insulate.
5. Spark went away, pipe stopped heating/cutting electrically. Other random components started heating up.

**Assumptions:**

1. A wire is stripped or poorly attached somewhere, leaking high voltage onto furnace body.
2. Going through the wires one by one, checking insulation and proper contact on splices will fix the problem. **There is no "fast" / methodical way to troubleshoot this.**
3. A bad ground is likely NOT the problem, as ideally, there shouldn't be voltage going to the furnace body itself.

Questions:

1. Are my assumptions correct? (Assume 101 understanding of electronics - I understand voltage, current, resistance, DC, relays, fuses etc, but I don't REALLY understand things like voltage converters or why a car battery or a furnace is grounded, for example, unless it's purely a safety mechanism that doesn't kick in unless there is a failure).
2. Any overall advice on trouble shooting this?
3. What safety precautions should I take? Other than the obvious - cut power, cut gas, wear insulated gloves, etc.

P.S. Obviously I will do this after the furnace is off, which it currently is, with the circuit breaker to it turned off as well.

P.S. 2 - an electrician and an HVAC professional looked at it, charged me $80 each and said it's not worth paying them to find what's wrong on such an old unit. This is the same story I get with old cars when there is a $2 30-minute fix.

Not my furnace, but looks like the same model.
[image]

---

Wiring diagram from my furnace:

[image]

Transformer (bare hands because breaker is turned off and input wire is completely disconnected):

[image]

[image]

Removing transformer:

[image]

Transformer input wires are spliced with a bunch of others. I had false expectations of single point connection to main.

[image]

11/14 Updates: I have to admit that I had expectations of magic connection terminals that connected via a metal loop and a bolt, rather than spliced wires. Nothing meaningful to report back yet, still working on it. So much for my 2 mins comment.

Disconnected:

[image]

**Updates on 11/16:**

- Did as John instructed (all tests with gas cut off, burner not on) - disconnected the two input wires to the transformer entirely, capped and isolated them, put everything else back together as it were.
- Turned on breaker, tried to turn on heat - nothing, no voltage to any of the components that were heating up before.
- Reconnected trans input wires - turned power back on, turned heat back on - nothing, no voltage anywhere.
- Edit: 20 minutes in - no voltage, no spark, transformer body is
  starting to heat on top. Barely warm so far.
- 50 minutes in - no voltage, transformer is getting warmer. All other parts of system cold.

My only guess is that I should have waited longer. I am now suspicious that the short starts appearing when the components heat up. Letting it run with no gas to see if problem comes back. If it doesn't come back in an hour, I will ventilate, check for gas, and turn the burner back on.

Note that I don't think that I magically "fixed" anything - all the connections looked really solid and properly isolated before I touched them. Also, sorry for the slow replies, I have been swamped at work.

P.S. - why does the transformer have two input wires? Also, if I can buy a replacement transformer for less than $50 and there is 40%+ chance that it's the problem, I think I want to try that next.

11/17: It ran for several hours, transformer heated up, but not anywhere near being hot enough to burn to the touch. No sparking. Turned on gas and lit it. Not seeing flames to heat exchanger. Next guess is whatever is responsible for gas not opening it.

Comment: The problem isn't the "$2 fix."  It's the hours long search for the cause of the problem, then being held responsible when the ancient pile of junk blows up next year because something else wore out.

Comment: Yea, I get that. I shouldn't have made that comment, but I am going to leave it in the post for the sake of the existing answer making sense. Nonetheless, I think there is an optimal solution here that strikes a happy medium between expense and reliability. I am willing to put in the time myself - is my general approach correct?

Comment: OK let's troubleshoot. Does it only spark when the stat is on (call for heat?) Can you put a test light or meter across the spark-spot. The 24 voltAC transformer may have a short between the windings. During testing you could shut off the gas or remove the wires going to the gas valve. These are first steps to finding the problem.

Comment: "The 24 voltAC transformer may have a short between the windings." thanks John - this would be my first guess since it looks to be in bad shape. It sparks regardless of the call for heat being on - if there is power to it, it's sparking and/or the furnace heats up in random spots. "Can you put a test light or meter across the spark-spot. " - yea, I will do that and report back. I apologize for my smartass "P.S.2" again.

Comment: In the same vein - would it be easier to just replace the transformer to eliminate it as the culprit? From what I understand (which, admittedly, isn't much) it's near impossible to identify it as the culprit without taking it off and trying to run current through it. If so, could someone link me to a replacement transformer I could by or tell me what to look for when trying to buy one? (I do get that it won't be plug and play, but I can figure out how to mount it and wire it up assuming the inputs and outputs are the same and it can handle the voltage/current).

Comment: The diagram really helps. If you remove one or better yet, both, of the input wires to the 24v transformer, then check for sparking. This eliminates all of the 24v circuits. Has the stat been changed or remounted? I would have to look up your old terminal letters. BTW on a newer furnace I have seen a sparker fail to operate because the basement renovators did not attach the bare copper ground wire in their temporary setup.

Comment: Thank you again. I will remove the input wires tomorrow and post back in the evening - there is some corrosion so I want to be careful. "Has the stat been changed or remounted" - yes, a new Honeywell unit was installed, presumably within the past 5 years based on how new it is. I actually don't know where the ground is yet, I will look for it.

Comment: @JohnCanon - I had a potentially dumb question - what if I isolate the transformer. Let's say there is a short between the coils and it's going back to the furnace body through the metal attachment point. What if I just hang it on plastic zipties for the sake of testing (so it doesn't connect to the body? Would that eliminate it as the root cause? Or is it potentially sending more voltage down the 24V wires and my "test" is useless? If this is at all helpful, I would rather do it before messing with the wire splicing.

Comment: No, no, no. The trans has 2 input and 2 output leads according to your diagram. If you remove any wiring use tape and a sharpie to tag and mark everything. Don't just rely on photos. I hope you have not removed any connections yet. Step 1: remove only the 2 input terminals and keep all other connections together. Use marettes or tape. With only those 2 leads disconnected, power up the furnace. Keep gas off. Does it spark? You have eliminated the trans and everything downwind of it. If it didn't spark, then reconnect and power up to confirm the problem still exists. Step 2 depends on results.

Comment: This should definitely be closed as a consumer repair question - it's designed for cases _exactly_ like this.

Comment: @pipe Where do I take these questions then? To the "Home Improvements" stack exchange? This seems to fall squarely under practical troubleshooting of electronics.

Comment: @VSO Everything these days has electronics, but consumer repair questions are off-topic when OP doesn't already know electronics. Such questions always turn into a long discussion about "did you try X?" and are way too broad, often requiring proprietary documents (basically to stop the flood of "My expensive TV broke, help me fix it" questions). I don't know where to take it. Stack Exchange is not meant to cover every question anyone can have, so maybe there's no place at all. It sounds on-topic on Home Improvement.

Comment: Don't get me wrong though, the quality of the question is exemplary. But should have been closed _early_ so you didn't have to spend so much time on editing so much.

Comment: @pipe Fair enough - if whoever closes it, oh well, it already helped me a ton.

Answer (score 1):

As both an experienced furnace man and a licensed auto mechanic, I am doing the math: a $2 fix that takes 30 minutes means I could make $4 per hour, if I had the time and inclination. If the furnace can have one worn-out part, it can have more worn-out bits, probably hidden until they bite. Looking for the problem will probably uncover other deficiencies, as both those professionals suspect. If you need to keep this furnace going, it needs professional TLC.

Comment: Not a useful answer. This site is a spin from stackoverflow, which wouldn't exist if everyone replied with "if you want a reliable site, hire a professional programmer". You are an auto-mechanic? This will sound familiar to you then - was told to replace ECU, turned out to be an O2 sensor. Was told engine needs replaced, needed to clean throttle body. I realize it's easier for you to sell me a new furnace than to troubleshoot some wiring - but I would rather pay you $80/hr to troubleshoot a short than pay $5000 for a furnace. Anyway - with no hostility - your answer does not help.

Comment: @VSO : but it's the right answer for this case. Stay safe and good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I will post an update here after I am done.

Comment: @VSO To remove transformer wires use electrical tape to hold the bundle together before unscrewing the wire nut all the way off. Then you will see the copper ends twisted together. Untwist and remove only the wire going to the transformer. Tag and mark everything. Twist the wire nut back on the remaining wires, but not loose. Do the same with the other transformer wire. Both wires on the PRI side of the coil are now disconnected. Now you have disconnected the transformer out of the circuit. Complete step 1 as I had described. I will edit my earlier answer if you have more questions.

Comment: @JohnCanon - updated, news at end of the post to avoid spamming chat. Let me know if I can add more detail. Btw, feel free to stop helping if you would like - you have already genuinely helped more than enough, and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @VSO Use history and symptoms to understand the specifics. Use the schematic diagram to see the building blocks of operation. Don't just change parts by guessing. Divide and conquer: disconnect certain subsystems to see if the problem stays or goes. By confirming the good, you get closer to the bad. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks John, I think you gave me the confidence (and great advice) to start. I should be good from here. Ty and see you around!

Comment: Normal opration: stat closes, gas valve turns on, furnace warms up and triggers blower fan. The gas valve is 24v and is in series with safety switches. Look at diagram, make sure 24v goes through limit switch and thermocouple and on to the gas valve. Look up operation, look at diagram, then follow the voltage until you find the break.

Comment: @JohnCanon See top of post!! Ty. Sorry to bother you again, but had to share.